# authenticate ASP.Net App on Azure WS2019 against Azure SQL via AAD - Access token could not be acquired No mapping between account names and securi

Tags: asp.net, entra-id, iis-10, azure-sql

I try to reconfigure our ASP.Net app with .Net Framework 4.7.2 from SQL username/password Auth. to token based Azure Active Directory Authentication by using the system assigned managed identity of the VM running the Web Site.

I started with https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell

Enabled AD Admin on SQL Server
created a AAD group, in which i added the SMI of the VM
created a User in SQL for each database with "FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER"

and i can logon to the SQL Server with SSMS using the AAD MFA Authentication.

On the VM i installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication
& https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

through copying the dlls to my bin directory of the website.

In the web.config i added the two SqlAuthenticationProviders sections with the public key token
and a reconfigured connection string:

add name="Master" connectionString="server=tcp:xxxxdb01.privatelink.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=master_dev;UID=app;Authentication=Active Directory Interactive;TrustServerCertificate=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

IIS, after several errors, not able to find the dlls, finally gave the error:

Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.windows.net/97293BC6-059A-4DCB-9520-7FF64761E91E. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Active Directory Integrated Authentication. Access token could not be acquired. Failed to get user name from the operating system.Inner Exception : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

I thought about the link between the "System assigned managed identity", which is authorized on the datebase, and the ASP.Net app, running on the VM. How does the IIS get the managed id to authenticate against SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

> IIS, after several errors, not able to find the dlls, finally gave the error:

This is most likely the issue here, IIS is unable to see those DLLs and is ignoring the connection string and reverting to use Integrated Authentication as per the error message.

Also, the authentication to AAD doesn't happen using IIS, it actually happens using the context of your app that is running on top of IIS, so what you need to configure is actually the app, not IIS.

More reading here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core2x

Comment: Thank you Noor !

I recently found out, that the vm is MI enabled (System identity). The error above is the last of the 4 methods, the AppAuthentication library trys to get a token from.

The first method, authorization through the system managed identity, stops with:Exception Message: "Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Operation is not supported on this platform".

Comment: i set the Env Var. "AzureServicesAuthConnectionString" to "RunAs=App", the Prov. is only trying to get the token through Managed Identity method. The following exception occurs: (same as the error before, but i didn't focus on the first method it trys). [AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: RunAs=App, Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.windows.net/9xxxx...E. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Operation is not supported on this platform.]